# how to remove double quote and \ from nested value

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I have written a code to convert list to json but I have a problem. When I test web method I see that I have `"` and `\` added to the nested object. I want to know how can I remove them using `JavaScriptSerializer()`.

```
var innerResult (linq query to get list of data).toList()
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(innerResult);
result = (from value1 in db.Values
          join value2 in db.Values on value1.ParentId equals value2.RecordId
          join value3 in db.Values on value1.RecordId equals value3.ParentId
          where
              value1.ParentId
              == (from va in db.Values where va.Name == formType select va.RecordId).FirstOrDefault()
          orderby value1.RecordId
          select
              new ItemManagementViewModel
                  {
                      FormType = value2.Name,
                      FormControllerID = value1.RecordId,
                      FormControllerName = value1.Name,
                      values = serializedResult
                  }).ToList();
return result;

public class ItemManagementViewModel 
{
    public string FormType { get; set; }
    public long FormControllerID { get; set; }
    public string FormControllerName { get; set; }

    public string values { get; set; }
}
```

json fomat update how can I remove double quote string  before square bracket  "[{\

```
{
     "formType": "registarForm",
     "formControllerID": 2,
     "formControllerName": "Conditions",
     "values": "[{\"recordId\":14,\"name\":\"Asthma\",\"parentId\":14},{\"recordId\":15,\"name\":\"Cardiac Conditions\",\"parentId\":15},{\"recordId\":16,\"name\":\"COPD\",\"parentId\":16},{\"recordId\":17,\"name\":\"CVA\",\"parentId\":17}]"
}
```

Comment: Why? If you are going to read that string using a json deserializer, it should be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want extra quotes, you should not serialize inner result twice. I.e. try to use the next code:

```
  select
      new ItemManagementViewModel
          {
              FormType = value2.Name,
              FormControllerID = value1.RecordId,
              FormControllerName = value1.Name,
              values = innerResult
          }).ToList();
```

And change the type of 'values' to appropriate one, i.e. List or YourEntities